# Issue with plotting logistic regression in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, logistic-regression

Say I have this data:

```
n = 1e3
x = rnorm(n)
linear_process = 1 + 5*x
y = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = plogis(linear_process))
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

I fit a GLM and make predictions:

```
m = glm(y~x, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
y_hat = predict(m, type = 'response')
```

and when I plot `y_hat` as points I get what I expected:

```
plot(x,y)
points(x,y_hat, col = 'blue')
```

[image]

but when I plot the predicted probabilities as a line I get this weird thing:

```
plot(x,y)
lines(x,y_hat, col = 'blue')
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong with `predict`? or `plot`?

Comment: Try `lines(sort(x),y_hat[order(x)], col = 'blue')`

Comment: `lines(cbind(x, y_hat)[order(x),], col='red')`